# Format the output of elasticsearch-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I'm trying to use the `python` client for `elasticsearch`. Here is a minimal example:

```python
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch as ES

print "Setup connection..."
es=ES(['localhost:8080'])
print "Done!"

print "Count number of users..."
print es.count(index='users')
```

The output is:

```json
{u'count': 836780, u'_shards': {u'successful': 5, u'failed': 0, u'total': 5}}
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I get rid of the `u'` (`u` followed by a single quote )?
2. <s>How can I extract the value of count? I guess I could do string manipulation, but that sounds like the wrong way....</s>
   Answer: if the output is saved to `res`, then `res['count'] returns the number`836780`.

Comment: I think it is a dictionary (of python), you should convert to json to remove 'u ' . look. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: The `u''` tells you that the string is Unicode (see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). That structure is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), string manipulation is definitely not the easiest approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

elasticsearch.py convert json response to dictionary for python, so that it is easy to extract information.

I.e

```
{u'count': 836780, u'_shards': {u'successful': 5, u'failed': 0, u'total': 5}}
```

is python dictionary.

If you wan to have it in json structure then you can do,

```
json.dumps()
```

look more [python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)