# convert python elasticsearch response to a table or csv

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Stealing this example ([Format the output of elasticsearch-py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990706/format-the-output-of-elasticsearch-py))

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch as ES

print "Setup connection..."
es=ES(['localhost:8080'])
print "Done!"

print "Count number of users..."
print es.count(index='users')
```

Results like:

```
{u'count': 836780, u'_shards': {u'successful': 5, u'failed': 0, u'total': 5 ... ... }}
```

Except what I want to do is convert ^ to a csv

Should I try to convert it back to json then to csv or anyway i can convert it directly?

Comment: Convert dictionary to json with json.loads(). Then flatten it. And then to csv

Comment: @Bayko I tried do this `data_list = get_cache_json(doc) json_data = json.loads(data_list)` but when I go to `print(json_data)` to see how it looks , it looks the same ie {u'count': 836780, u'_shards' ... am I missing a step?

Comment: Sorry about that apporach. I think this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file  . Your 'results' is a csv